# Composer is not working or returning anything when run

Tags: macos, composer-php

Composer will not execute, or display any messages. When I try to install a package it just returns with no response. I try executing composer -v and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer run in PHP, so PHP configuration is used.

Look at your PHP configuration in your shell :

Watch for `log_errors` and `display_errors` parameters

```
$ php --info | grep "errors"
display_errors => Off => Off
log_errors => On => On
```

If everything is set to `Off`, consider changing your config

```
$ php --info | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

And edit the given file.

Comment: I should have known the check the config, this is a great lead and am now getting return text. Thank you!